# UILabel won't adjust height to fit content

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't get this dynamic label to resize its height according to the content.  It logs the correct info but the label is always the same height.  Any ideas? (code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/447065))

```
        self.descriptionLabel.text = string;
        self.descriptionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
      
        
        self.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines=0;
        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);
        
        CGSize expectedLabelSize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        
        //adjust the label the the new height.
        CGRect newFrame = self.descriptionLabel.frame;
        newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
        NSLog(@"the height %f", newFrame.size.height);
        self.descriptionLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: Are you using layout constraints in Storyboarding?

Comment: You got it!! I thought my code would override any constraints.  oops

Answer (score 0):

```
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(requiredWidth, MAXFLOAT);

        CGSize labelSize = [requiredLableText sizeWithFont:requiredFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        returned size will give u the dynamic height of the UILabel
```