# How add Multiple Lines in Same UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

Any way to have multiple lines of text in UILabel ?

I dont wish to more than 1 label in the view.

How to add multiple lines in a single UILabel??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way. Just you need to add two property of `UILabel` i.e.

1. `NumberOfLines=0` It'll allow you to add multiple lines in a `UILabel`
2. `LineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` It'll allow you to break your sentence by word. You can also change it according to your requirement.

   ```
   [YourLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
   [YourLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
   ```

You can also set this two property form your interface builder

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample code

```
    UILabel  *pHolder1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 245, 45)];
    pHolder1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    pHolder1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    pHolder1.numberOfLines =0;
    pHolder1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    pHolder1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Dynamically calculate the height of UILabel
please refer the below post
[Adjust UILabel height depending on the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text)

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code:

```
    UILabel *lblUsername=[[UILabel alloc] init];
    StoryTextSize = [storytext sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:13.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    lblUsername.frame=CGRectMake(20, 5, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-40, StoryTextSize.height);
    lblUsername.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    lblUsername.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[tblRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"username"]];
    lblStoryText.numberOfLines=nooflines;
    lblStoryText.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:lblStoryText];
```

make sure that your label height should be more so total no of lines become visible.