# iOS auto adjust label height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, cgrect

I'm using the following code to auto adjust the height of a label in a UITableView.  It works the majority of the time, but certain times text is cut off.  Is there something wrong with my code, or anything else I need to add? (code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/447065))

```
UILabel *textLabel = ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3]);
textLabel.text = text;

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:textLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:textLabel.lineBreakMode];

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = textLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
textLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: Did you set lineBreakMode to BreakByWordWrapping and numberOfLines to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 7 `sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode:` is deprecated, now you should use:

```
 CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(296.f, FLT_MAX);
 CGRect labRect = [someText boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textLabel.font} context:nil];


 textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, maxSize.width, labRect.size.height);
 textLabel.text = someText;
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it wants to know the value of width.  It also wanted x and y, but I'm assuming they're 0 and 0.  For width would it just be the width of the screen?

Comment: @Jhorra yes width is width of the screen or less.. for example 296 as maxSize width