# (entire page) Scroll view for MutableArray Label

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, xcode5

I have a page view where I have different lines of tekst in a label.
On most of my pages I have no problem, because there is enough text in the label to be shown on the standard 3.5/4 inch size.

I've found some tutorials like this, but the give me a standard size tot scroll.
I want it to be mutable with my array labels.

I've coded my object like this (if needed):

```
photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Photo *pic = [[Photo alloc]init];
pic.name = @"Papier en karton";
pic.filename = @"papier";
pic.notes = @"Oude kranten, tijdschriften en karton (zoals platgeslagen dozen) doet u in de papiercontainer. Zet géén dozen bij het grofvuil, maar breng ze naar een afvalpunt of maak de dozen klein en doe ze in de papiercontainer.";
[photos addObject:pic];

pic = [[Photo alloc]init];
pic.name = @"Frituurvet";
pic.filename = @"frituur";
pic.notes = @"Frituurvet kan nog prima hergebruikt worden als biobrandstof. Gooi het daarom nooit weg, maar breng het naar een afvalpunt. Zie ook www.frituurvetrecyclehet.nl";
[photos addObject:pic];

pic = [[Photo alloc]init];
pic.name = @"Klein chemisch afval";
pic.filename = @"chemisch";
pic.notes = @"Op zaterdag kunt u in het centrum op een vaste plek terecht om uw batterijen, kleine elektrische apparaten, medicijnen, verfresten en agressieve vloeistoffen als chloor, ammoniak en terpentine in te leveren:\n\n- Eerste zaterdag van de maand\nOchtend 09.00-12.30 uur Haarlemmerdijk, tegenover Albert Heijn.\nMiddag 13.00-16.30 uur Sarphatistraat en Ir Jakoba Mulderplein tegenover Albert Heijn.\n- Tweede zaterdag van de maand\nOchtend 09.00-12.30 uur Kleine Wittenburgerstraat tegenover Albert Heijn.\nMiddag 13.00-16.30 uur Kerkstraat bij Vijzelgracht tegenover Albert Heijn.\n- Derde zaterdag van de maand\nOchtend 09.00-12.30 uur Elandsgracht tegenover Albert Heijn.\nMiddag 13.00-16.30 uur Jodenbreestraat tegenover Albert Heijn.\n- Vierde zaterdag van de maand\nOchtend 09.00-12.30 uur Nieuwmarkt tegenover Albert Heijn.\nMiddag 13.00-16.30 uur Sarphatistraat/Spinozastraat tegenover Albert Heijn.\n\nAls een maand vijf zaterdagen heeft, wordt de vijfde zaterdag overgeslagen.";
[photos addObject:pic];
```

I'll show them here in my custom ViewController:

```
#import "DisplayViewController.h"

@interface DisplayViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *currentImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailsLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;

@end

@implementation DisplayViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.currentphoto.filename];
    [self.currentImage setImage:image];

    self.detailsLabel.text = [self.currentphoto notes];

    self.titleLabel.text = [self.currentphoto name];

}
```

My question is:
How can I make a Page View were my hight is as long as my Label text is?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I make a Page View were my hight is as long as my Label text is?

Comment: see this link to calculate size of uilabel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text . then adjust pageview size according to it