# Unable to change correct UITableViewCell Height According to the label Text in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

Sometimes i am not getting correct UITableViewCell height. My table cell contains three labels   as i have mentioned in the attached screenshot. please check my below code and help me to fix this issue.

[image]

here is my code :

```
-(CGFloat)getTextHeightForIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(242, 10000);

    Agenda *agenda = [[Agenda alloc] init];
    agenda = [arrayMyAgenda objectAtIndex:index];

    NSString *strTotalText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@  %@", agenda.program_name, agenda.program_hall, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", agenda.pg_start_time, agenda.pg_end_time]];

    CGSize labelHeightSize = [strTotalText sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0f]
                                     constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                                         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return labelHeightSize.height +20;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return  1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arrayMyAgenda count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self getTextHeightForIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Agenda *myAgenda = [[Agenda alloc] init];
    myAgenda = [self.arrayMyAgenda objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(!cell) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        UILabel *lblTitleText   = nil;
        UILabel *lblAreaText  = nil;
        UILabel *lblTimingText   = nil;

        //First label for Title
        lblTitleText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 6, 305, 24)];
        lblTitleText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
        lblTitleText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblTitleText.text = myAgenda.program_name;
        lblTitleText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        lblTitleText.numberOfLines = 0;
        lblTitleText.tag = 10;
        [lblTitleText sizeToFit];
        lblTitleText.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(59/255.0) green:(59/255.0) blue:(59/255.0) alpha:1.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitleText];

        //Second label for Area name
        lblAreaText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, lblTitleText.frame.size.height + 4, 305, 21)];
        lblAreaText.text = myAgenda.program_hall;
        lblAreaText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
        lblAreaText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblAreaText.tag = 20;
        lblAreaText.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(161/255.0) green:(163/255.0) blue:(160/255.0) alpha:1.0];
        lblAreaText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        lblAreaText.numberOfLines = 0;
        [lblAreaText sizeToFit];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblAreaText];

        //Third label for timings
        lblTimingText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, lblTitleText.frame.size.height + lblAreaText.frame.size.height + 2, 305, 21)];
        lblTimingText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", myAgenda.pg_start_time, myAgenda.pg_end_time];
        lblTimingText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
        lblTimingText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblTimingText.tag = 30;
        lblTimingText.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(161/255.0) green:(163/255.0) blue:(160/255.0) alpha:1.0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTimingText];

        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        ((UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10]).text = myAgenda.program_name;
        ((UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20]).text = myAgenda.program_hall;
        ((UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:30]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", myAgenda.pg_start_time, myAgenda.pg_end_time];

        UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
        selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRowSelected.png"]];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;

        cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"recentchatcell.jpg"]];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should follow up this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21984749/675170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you get the height of combined strings that will display into three different labels. You should get each string's height that will go to each label and add them to get the cell height. Doesn't it make more sense getting height of each labels from the string that will display on them and add them together to get the cell height?

Try this:

```
-(CGFloat)getTextHeightForIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(305, 10000);

Agenda *agenda = [[Agenda alloc] init];
agenda = [arrayMyAgenda objectAtIndex:index];

CGFloat cellHeight = 0;

CGSize titleLabelHeightSize = [agenda.program_name sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0f]
                                  constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                                      lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
cellHeight += titleLabelHeightSize.height > 24 ? titleLabelHeightSize.height : 24;

CGSize areaLabelHeightSize = [agenda.program_hal sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0f]
                                  constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                                      lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
cellHeight += areaLabelHeightSize.height > 21 ? areaLabelHeightSize.height : 21;

CGSize timinglLabelHeightSize = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", agenda.pg_start_time, agenda.pg_end_time] sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0f]
                                  constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                                      lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
cellHeight += timinglLabelHeightSize.height > 21 ? timinglLabelHeightSize.height : 21;
return cellHeight +20;
```

}

You can generalize this function more but I think this is good enough for your need.

Comment: @HMHeroThanks, I have tried your above code but still my problem is remain same.

Comment: @user2786 Does it look as same as your original one does? There was a mistake. Change CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(242, 10000); to CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(305, 10000);

Comment: @user2786 and remove [lblTitleText sizeToFit]; and [lblAreaText sizeToFit];

Comment: I have made mistake with the same CGSize maximumSize. After replacing with 300 its working. Thanks alot..

Comment: @HMHeroPls change your answer with correct CGSize maximumSize width coordinate... so it will help for other guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `-(CGFloat)getTextHeightForIndex:(NSInteger)index`: instead of `CGSize` use `CGRect`. Worked for me.

```
CGRect labelHeightSize = [strTotalText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(280.f, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0f]} context:nil];
return ceilf(labelHeightSize.size.height) + 50.0f;
```