# How to change cell's height programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UItableView with cells. Each cell has a button. How to do that when I click on the button cell's height increased?

Comment: follow up this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21984749/675170

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
#pragma mark - Table View
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Item *object = listData[indexPath.row];  


    if (object.buttonClicked) {
        return 300;
    }else{
        return 100;
    }

}
```

Comment: How does this change the row's height when a button is tapped in the cell?

Comment: This can work if reloadData is called after button tap

Comment: And do not forget to save the state of your button on each row!