# Resize UILabel view IOS

Tags: ios, label, autosize

Hi I am new to iPhone development. I want to resize my label. I know this question asked many times previously but those answers not working for me. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I did following things :
I am using auto layout. I also define number of line to 0. then to resize my label I did following things

```
NSString *text = @"NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID “;
_sampleText.text = text;
CGRect newSize = _sampleText.frame;
newSize.size.height = 200.0f;
_sampleText.frame = newSize;
```

I tried `[_sampleText sizeToFit];` this also.

But this not working for me. Any one can help me please. Need Help. Thank you.

I tried this one

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(_sampleText.frame.size.width, 999);
CGSize expectedSize = [text boundingRectWithSize: maximumSize options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                            attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:_sampleText.font.fontName size:_sampleText.font.pointSize] } context: nil].size;
[_sampleText setText:text];
[_sampleText sizeToFit];
CGRect rect = _sampleText.frame;
rect.size.height = expectedSize.height;
_sampleText.frame = rect;
```

Forgot about text and resizing with text I am not able to resize Uilabel it self

```
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
  [_sampleText setFrame:rect];
```

above code inside viewDidLoad.

So I found some thing. If I disable auto layout option then it works fine. But what if I want to use it with auto layout enable?

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text) might help you out. Don't forget to vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `calculate size` to `fit` in `UILabel`:

```
NSString *text = @"NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID NILESH KASHID";
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(_sampleText.frame.size.width, 999);
CGSize expectedSize = [text sizeWithFont:_sampleText.font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[_sampleText setText:text];
[_sampleText sizeToFit];
CGRect rect = _sampleText.frame;
rect.size.height = expectedSize.height;
_sampleText.frame = rect;
```

Comment: thank you for replay I tried your solution but its not working sir :(

Comment: I have jus simple UIlabel and not even applying any constraints on it. What will be reason behind this ?

Comment: If I disable auto layout then it works fine. But what if I want to use it with auto layout ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *text = @"";
        CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(300, 1500.0f);
        CGSize requiredSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]
                               constrainedToSize:boundingSize
                                   lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        CGFloat requiredHeight = requiredSize.height;
       int textHeight = requiredHeight+90;
        NSLog(@"%d",textHeight);
        return textHeight;
```

Try this...All the best!!!!

Comment: `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` deprecated since IOS7.

Comment: instead u can use  CGSize requiredSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]
                               constrainedToSize:boundingSize];text.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

Comment: If I disable auto layout then it works fine. But what if I want to use it with auto layout ?

Comment: you are restricting the label with constraints to fit in particulr place by using auto layout.

Comment: But I am not putting any constraints.

Comment: yes,now you might disabled.If you use constraints,the label will stick to that position.

Comment: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                            attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:_sampleText.font.fontName size:_sampleText.font.pointSize] } context: nil].size;

Comment: that will be used only in ios7,in ios6 it leads to crash