# Get height of string with font

Tags: ios, uifont

I am having the hardest time figuring out how to get the size, specifically the height, of a `UILabel` containing specified text and using a specified font. Basically, I want a method that returns the height for a given string and font.

This is what I have so far:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForString:(NSString *)string withFontSize:(CGFloat)size
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:size]};

    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string
                                                                           attributes:attributes];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    CGRect paragraphRect =
    [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                 options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                 context:nil];

    return paragraphRect.size.height;
}
```

This returns a height that is about half the size it should be. I know this question has been asked a million times, but none of the solutions work fully.

Comment: Try to use this solution->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text

I hope it help you.

Comment: MobiDevCom that solution uses sizeWithFont...That method was deprecated in iOS7. Thanks though!

Comment: In the past I've simply created a dummy label, inserted the text, and then used the option (forget which one) to squeeze the label down to the minimum size that fits the text.  Sometimes I create a single global label just for this temporary use.  (The label does not need to be in a view anywhere.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to simply create a dummy label, set it's text property and set `numberOfLines` to 0 and say `[label sizeToFit]` that will allow you to get the frame of the label, which includes the height. It's not an ideal way, but it works.

Apparently in iOS 8 there will be [self sizing table view cells](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-8-self-sizing-table-view-cells-with-dynamic-type/)! Cannot wait!

Answer (score 1):

Use this category to calculate height of text with given font and max width, which is used in in [SOMessaging](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMessaging/blob/master/SOMessaging/NSString+Calculation.h)

Basically I made it as replacement of `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode` method of iOS6