# Change the height of UILabel dynamically based on content

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, ios7.1, xcode5.1

I have a `UILabel` as subview of `UIButton` and I am passing the value
from another view and populating in `UILabel`. Now, I want that `UILabel`
must change its height based on the content.If text is "Hello" it must
be in 1 line but if text is " my text is too long to fit in the
label", it must change its size. I have used

```
   [self.addressLabel sizeToFit];
```

But for this i need to leave empty space below UILabel. Simply what I
want is that when text strength increases,size of UILabel and UIView
must expand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust UILabel height depending on the text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using below you can get the height of the label

- text - text of the label
- font - font used in label
- width - width of the label

  ```
  -(float) getHeightForText:(NSString*) text withFont:(UIFont*) font andWidth:(float) width{
      CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(width , 20000.0f);
      CGSize title_size;
      float totalHeight;

      SEL selector = @selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:);
      if ([text respondsToSelector:selector]) {                
          title_size = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : font }
                                          context:nil].size;

          totalHeight = ceil(title_size.height); 
      } else {                
          title_size = [text sizeWithFont:font
                        constrainedToSize:constraint
                            lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];                
          totalHeight = title_size.height ;                
      }

      CGFloat height = MAX(totalHeight, 40.0f);
      return height;            
  }
  ```

and create a frame using the height

```
CGRect frame = questionTitleLbl.frame;

float height = [self getHeightForText:questionTitleLbl.text 
                             withFont:questionTitleLbl.font
                            andWidth:questionTitleLbl.frame.size.width];
float gap = 2;

cell.questionTitleLbl.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, 
                                         frame.origin.y, 
                                         frame.size.width, 
                                         height);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i am not using table view.it is just view controller.

Comment: @iDev, that is just a buffer height I have added , you can ignore that if not required , anyhow I have updated the code .

Comment: Can someone please tell me how can this be achieved using auto layout in a `UITableViewCell` or `UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: @Smarto, read this stack overflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/1730345.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way that i handle this issue:

```
UILabel *sight = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
sight.text=tmpGroup.title;

sight.frame =CGRectMake(sight.frame.origin.x, sight.frame.origin.y, 191, 21);


sight.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"RobotoSlab-Bold" size:10];


sight.numberOfLines=0;
sight.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

[sight sizeToFit];
```

Comment: sizeToFit is necessary

Answer (score 1):

Use this code its very easy and updated with ios8

add this method to your appconstant file

```
inline static CGSize getLabelHeightForFont(NSString *fontName,NSString* str, float fontSize, float lblWidth)
{
    NSString *text = str;
    CGFloat width = lblWidth;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];

    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:text
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: font
     }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    return rect.size;


}
```

and finally use this code for dynamic create UILabel

```
CGFloat lbl_height = getLabelHeightForFont(@"System- System", address, 15, lbl_address.frame.size.width);
    lbl_address.numberOfLines = 0;
    lbl_address.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [lbl_address setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    lbl_address.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_address.frame.origin.x, lbl_address.frame.origin.y, lbl_address.frame.size.width, lbl_height+5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the very simplest function for getting dynamic height for labels. You can just use this function.
  Here ceil is the predefind function for returns the smallest integer value.
And MAXHEIGHT is maximum height for uilabel for example you can give 1000 also for future caluclations...

```
-(CGFloat) getHeightForLabels : (UILabel *) label
    {

        CGSize widthMaxHeight = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, MAXHEIGHT);
        CGSize size;

        NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
        CGSize boundingRect = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:widthMaxHeight
                                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                   attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                                      context:context].size;

        size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingRect.width), ceil(boundingRect.height));

        return size.height;
    }
```