# How to resize uilabel using content?

Tags: autolayout, resize, uilabel, constraints

I'm trying to resize the uilabel using content, I tried in autolayout ios with cgrectmake, but it's not working.

```
cell.msglabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, myLabel.frame.size.width, myLabel.frame.size.height)];
cell.msglabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[cell.msglabel setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, myLabel.frame.size.width, myLabel.frame.size.height)];
cell.msglabel.text=text;
[cell.msglabel updateConstraints];
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157209/change-the-height-of-uilabel-dynamically-based-on-content

Comment: tanq  Subin K Kuriakose  it is working need ecstimate number of lines also

Answer (score 1):

UILabel is intrinsicContentSize view which you need not to set frame directly when you using auto layout.

Give edge constraints is enough, width/height constraint are not necessary.
eg. left padding and top padding to other views.

Comment: tried John Henry as u said still my uilabel content is not geting incresed height and number of lines aumatically based on content

Comment: yes u r right label are intrinsicContentSize we just give to edge constraints and  number of lines tanq