# How to set UILabel height dynamically in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to create UILabel dynamically. I need to change its hight and the Y position according to data from webservice.
My code is like this

```
 NSMutableArray *remarkarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            remarkarray=[responsedict valueForKey:@"Key"];
            NSString *RemarkString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[remarkarray objectAtIndex:0]];
            remarklbl.text=RemarkString;
            remarklbl.numberOfLines=0;
            [remarklbl sizeToFit];
```

I have create UILabel like this

[image]

But its Y Position is fix. I need to create a UILabel in which I can change the height and the Y position according to text in it. Like this

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can u elobrate which I can change the height and the Y position according to text in it.

Comment: You can use autolayout and create constraints between the rows to ensure a fixed spacing between labels, regardless of how many lines the labels could grow to

Comment: you want to change the label height based on text

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157209/change-the-height-of-uilabel-dynamically-based-on-content

Comment: see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yes I want to change both label height and Y position..

Comment: @Muju - I understand see once the duplicate answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it very easily by declaring two labels in Storyboard.

Here are steps.

1. Drag two UILabels in your viewController and select the first one and set constraints like below image.

[image]

2. Select the second label and add following constraints.

[image]

3. Select both labels and set `numberOfLines` to zero.

Now u can set text dynamically from code.

[image: Adding text from code...]
[image: Output here..]

Comment: How the labels is dynamic in this answer?

Comment: Bcoz I am setting numberOfLine to zero and have not set label's height to be fixed. So, it will set automatically as per the content of label.

Comment: It will automatically set the height of the label not the dynamics labels.

Comment: Yes, it will set the height of label. and only this was the question .

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
 float x=10.0,y=10.0,height=40;
 float verticalSpace=20.0;


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
    UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y,50,height)];
    label.text = @"dummy text";// It could be from array as well if you want to add different text for each label. Eg:  label.text =  [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    y = y +height+ verticalSpace;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search around with key word "auto layout dynamic label height"