# How resize UIView With inner UITextView using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, autolayout

Hi i want to know how to use `autolayout` to achieve this behavior:

- In picture #1 is my `viewcontroller` contains with 3 `uiview` embedded with `uitextview`, as you can see the uiview dont allow the `uitextview` to show its full text.
- So i want to know how could i use autolayout to resize the uiview in order that inner uitextview can show the full text like picture #2.

---

**Picture #1:**

[image]

---

**Picture #2:**

[image]

Comment: Do you have constraints set up between the UILabel and the UITextView in each of your views? You need them!

Comment: yeah i do use autolayout in the picture #1, but i dont know what constraints are needed to let uiview expand with uitextview, uiview have a height constraint fixed to 85

Comment: Not sure if I understand -- why is it constrained to 85 if you want it to resize?

Comment: did u solve the problem

Comment: @nischalhada apparently not. Could you please check out my problem? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352629/how-to-add-two-uitextviews-into-a-uiview)

Comment: Hi dude can u set up the GitHub projects so that i can implement auto layout constraints to solve your problem regarding this problem

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the  size of ui view container increases with the description text Here is an approach you can follow.Use a uilabel instead of uitextview.
    Structure

```
<UIView>
     <UILabel for header>
     </UILabel>
    <UILabel for text>
     </UILabel>
</UiView>
```

1)Add a top spacing constraint between header uilabel and uiview

2)Add a bottom spacing constraint between text uilabel and uiview.

3)Add a spacing constraint between 2 uilabels

3)Add a height constraint for the description uilabel .Obtain height for the uilabel based on this [Adjust UILabel height depending on the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text) and then add the required height.

Also if you instead want  fixed height for uiview then you will have to use uitextview instead of desc uilabel and add scrollable property to texview.

Answer (score -1):

I set up a simple project that successfully resizes in iOS 8.  See [project on GitHub.](https://github.com/ksoftllc/UITableView-with-UITextView-and-UILabel-Resize)

Comment: This solution has nothing to do with the question