# How to add two UITextViews into a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to add two `UITextViews` into a `UIView` which is placed in a `UIStackView`. It works if I set width and height of the `UITextViews`. The problem is I do not know how to place them equally inside the `UIView` without setting width and height. The result should be like this:

[image]

```
class PanelCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let currentRunView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x1A1A1A)

        return view
    }()

    let totalRunView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x1A1A1A)

        return view
    }()

    let totalRunText: UITextView = {
        let text = UITextView(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 10))
        text.text = "Total run"
        text.textColor = .currentSpeedColor

        return text
    }()

    let totalRunValue: UITextView = {
        let text = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 10))
        text.text = "1220 km"
        text.textColor = .white

        return text
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        totalRunView.addSubview(totalRunValue)
        totalRunView.addSubview(totalRunText)

        let dashboardStackView = UIStackView()
        dashboardStackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
        dashboardStackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
        dashboardStackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
        dashboardStackView.spacing   = 12.0
        dashboardStackView.addArrangedSubview(currentRunView)
        dashboardStackView.addArrangedSubview(totalRunView)
        dashboardStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

        addSubview(dashboardStackView)

        _ = dashboardStackView.anchor(topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: -frame.width * 0.1, leftConstant: 25, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 25, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: frame.width * 0.25)

        backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x212121)
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to do this programatically? This looks like it would be simple to do by setting constraints in a Storyboard.

Comment: @PedroCastilho yep programmatically. I can see it as well using a storyboard would be much easier.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you to do that using Storyboard?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev yes it is. I use swipe view and on top of it  a UISegmentedControl which has to remain on the same position every time I swipe ([Screenshot](https://ibb.co/nNTS5k)).

Comment: What stops you from creating the constraints programatically then? Take a look at `NSLayoutConstraint` documentation and go from there. Draw your constraints on a piece of paper, and then recreate them in code.

Comment: Hi dude can u set up the GitHub projects so that i can implement auto layout constraints to solve your problem

Comment: @nischalhada please check [this](https://github.com/MGritsenko/RBWL) link out

Comment: @Losiowaty lack of knowledge, thank you for your suggestion to look at `NSLayoutConstraint`

Comment: @Losiowaty finally I have managed to make it work. I read and watched some tutorials and now I know little more.

Comment: Great! It's also totally fine on SO to post an answer to your own question, so go ahead and share it for future readers!