# ScrollView can't fit it's subview's content sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to let the user to adjust himself the font size to read the content of the app. therefor i put a slider that if the user swipe right, the fonts will grow and left means that the fonts size will be smaller. it works fine, but **the problem** is that sometimes the scrollView content size is not getting the new content size.
This is my method:

```
- (IBAction)enlargeLabelWithSlider:(id)sender{

UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
int font = 0;
int currentSliderValue = (int)slider.value;

if (currentSliderValue<=lastSilderValue) /* Every time the method call, at the end lastSilderValue = currentSliderValue*/
{
    // Need to increase
    font =lastSilderValue - currentSliderValue;

    [self.gameTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.gameTitleLabel.font.fontName size:self.gameTitleLabel.font.pointSize+font]];
    [self.gameScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.gameScoreLabel.font.fontName size:self.gameScoreLabel.font.pointSize+font]];
    self.gameStateLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.gameStateLabel.font.pointSize+font];
}
else
{
    // Need to decrease
    font =currentSliderValue - lastSilderValue;

    [self.gameTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.gameTitleLabel.font.fontName size:self.gameTitleLabel.font.pointSize-font]];
    [self.gameScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.gameScoreLabel.font.fontName size:self.gameScoreLabel.font.pointSize-font]];
    self.gameStateLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.gameStateLabel.font.pointSize-font];
}
lastSilderValue = currentSliderValue;

CGFloat height = self.gameStateLabel.frame.origin.y+self.gameStateLabel.frame.size.height+20; 
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.ScrollView.frame.size.width, height);
self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height); // i used self.gameStateLabel.frame.origin.y because it's the last label on the view.
```

}

can someone tell me why is this happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any change to the `UILabel` frame.
Maybe you have to adapt this frame to the new font size and then try to modify the scrollview contentSize property.
This will be helpful: [Adjust UILabel height depending on the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text)

Comment: i gave the UILabels constraints at the InterfaceBuilder and set numberOfLines to 0 there...the labels adjust correctly to the new font size.. the problem is that only sometimes the scrollView is not getting the correct size...