# Multiline UILabel not working in Notification Content Extension

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios-app-extension

I've put a UILabel in my notification content extension storyboard and set it up using auto layout. I've also set the numberOfLines to 0. In the storyboard, it looks perfectly fine but when I use it on my device, the label is coming out to be a single line. Am I missing anything?

Edit (ScreenShots added):

[image]

[image]

Also, when a new notification comes, I see a blank info and it's updated after a few secs.

[image]

**More ScreenShots Added:**

Number of lines is set to 0.

and in the code I'm setting it like this:

```
titleString.text = "Saturday SuperBowl Saturday SuperBowl Saturday SuperBowl"
```

But still it is coming as a single line.

[image]

Comment: do you ... at the end of 1 line label? if yes, might be you are setting programmatically as 1 line... if no, somewhere you are messing with constrains...

Comment: No it's set as 0 lines. And the problem is happening with this extension only.

Comment: do you see ... at the end of label? can you post screenshot...

Comment: I've added the screenshot.

Comment: Set Line Break to `Word Wrap` instead of `Truncate Tail`

Comment: @spassas It still doesn't make it multiline.

Comment: set it as 2 and double check

Comment: Then something is wrong with the constraints. Perhaps give the label's content compression resistance priority higher value than the MapView's

Comment: @spassas Did you try setting up a multiline label on a notification content extension storyboard?

Comment: Yes, multiline labels are working fine on notification content storyboards

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the constraints. What constraints have you set on the other views?

Comment: I've removed all the other views. Please check the updated question.

Comment: I think problem is Bottom space constraint...

Comment: [check this... might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text)

Comment: Thanks but that answer is not related with autolayout.

Comment: Hey @BhavukJain I have run into the same issue. Have you a solution for this?

Comment: @TomKraina I haven't tried it for a while now, but earlier I increased the height of UILabel so it manages to take up 2 lines max. This also makes sense for not allowing multiline via autolayout as the content should not go pass the screen height otherwise the notification will look weird.

Comment: @BhavukJain so you set a fixed height for the UILabel?

Comment: @TomKraina Yeah

Comment: I think this issue only occur on iOS < 10.3

Answer (score 1):

You must set the uilabels preferredMaxLayoutWidth. You can do this in your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    titleString.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = titleString.frame.size.width
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

or subclassing your uilabel:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width
    super.layoutSubviews
}
```

Comment: I'm using autolayout.

Comment: Even so you have to use what I wrote above!