# How to dynamically set the width and Height with autolayout of UILabel in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm new in iOS and facing issue regarding to set the width and height of UILabel. There are many answer on this question but nothing help me.

[image]

As in the image both label get overlap. I need that the below label according to upper label text. How to do that I also try AutoLayout and I 'm using code like this

I need to set the UILabel Height Auto according to text. 
like this

[image]

[image]

```
[lblSiteName setNumberOfLines:0];
[lblSiteName sizeToFit];
```

I'm using .XIB .How to do this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text

Comment: give your label hight constrain greater then equal and set number of line 0 and write one method that find your text hight and set it to your label

Comment: -(CGSize)findHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
    if (text) {
        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
        size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, ceil(frame.size.height));
    }
    return size;
}

Comment: @Muju, What do you exactly want? Your second label will just stay below your first label's text with some padding? or aligned with `clientname`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust UILabel height depending on the text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text)

Comment: @iPeter No Padding. Client Label should be swap down according to text of Site Name Label.That I want.

Comment: I recommend to use AutoLayout.  Both links above are old and no longer applicable since the accepted answer gives the wrong solution.

Comment: You can make outlets of Height and width constraint of UILabel and set them dynamically or you can set width and height constraint less than or greater than of particular size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
+ (CGSize) labelSize: (UILabel *) label
{
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
    CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
    return labelSize;
}
```

By this code you can get the fix size of the String for given UIFont.

Comment: How to call this method.

Comment: `UIlabel *label = [UIlabel alloc]initwith: Frame];`
`label.font = yourFont;`
`CGSize  labelSize = [self labelSize:label];`
`label.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);`

Comment: `sizeWithFont` has been deprecated a while now, use `sizeWithAttributes:` instead.