# UILabel text gets truncated with large font size

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

The text inside my UILabel in Interface Builder is being truncated when the text is a large font size. The UILabel does scroll vertically when the characters exceed the viewport size, but at one point the text is simply truncated. Can anyone advise?

The element hierarchy is: Scroll View > View > UILabel

UILabel AutoLayout properties are set to:

- Lines: 0
- Line Break: Word Wrap
- Autoshrink: Fixed Font Size

I would prefer to keep everything in AutoLayout rather than set the properties programmatically.

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36862795/4910767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are set the property of Label. So that according to device its set font size is auto.

**Autoshrink : Minimum Font scale**

**Scale : 0.7**

[image]

Comment: Does this shrink the font size? I would like it to remain the same size

Comment: Then You have to dynamically change height of label according to text and font Size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `**`**Minimum font Size**`**  &&`**Minimum font Scale**`

[image]