# UIView loading from xib need to resize dynamically with label text

Tags: ios, uiview, xib, ios-autolayout

I am loading a custom `UIView` from **xib**. The `UILabel` text may be long with multiline. There is a `UIButton` below the `UILabel`. The `UIView` is loading as a **custom subclass from the xib**.

I need to resize whole `UIView` depending on the amount of text. But it is keeping the frame height which is set in **xib**. How can resize the `UIView` elastically with the `UILabel` text, as well as keep all the `autolayout` constraint intact.

I need the `UIView` frame size since I am showing it as a drop down view from top with animation.

The `UILabel` is sized ok. But text goes beyond `UIView`. The `UIView` need to be resized and I need the updated frame size.

[image: xib with constraints]

Problem is showing here,
[image]

These lines fixes the **autoresize**, but I am not sure that's the right way.

```
CGRect myFrame = self.frame;
self.frame = CGRectMake(myFrame.origin.x, myFrame.origin.y, 
    myFrame.size.width, 
    self.labelMessage.frame.size.height + self.btClose.frame.size.height + 16); // magic number!
```

The whole class,

```
    #import "MessageView.h"

@implementation MessageView

@synthesize systemMessage = _systemMessage; //otherwise setter is not called

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self updateUI];
}

- (void) updateUI {
//  DLog(@"%@", _systemMessage);
    if (_systemMessage.actionType == MessageActionDisappearing || _systemMessage.actionType == MessageActionDismissableRetry) {
        _btTryAgain.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        _btTryAgain.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (_systemMessage.actionType == MessageActionDismissable || _systemMessage.actionType == MessageActionDismissableRetry) {
        _btClose.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        _btClose.hidden = YES;
    }
    _borderView.backgroundColor = [self getBorderColor];
    _labelMessage.text = _systemMessage.message;
    CGRect myFrame = self.frame;
    self.frame = CGRectMake(myFrame.origin.x, myFrame.origin.y, myFrame.size.width,
                            self.labelMessage.frame.size.height + self.btClose.frame.size.height + 16); // magic number!
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
//  DLog(@"");
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self xibSetup];
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
//  DLog(@"");
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
//  DLog(@"");
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self.subviews.count == 0) {
        [self xibSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) xibSetup {
    UIView *v = [self loadViewFromXib];
    v.frame = self.bounds;
    [self addSubview:v];
}

- (UIView *)loadViewFromXib {
    UIView *v = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MessageView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    return v;
}

// isn't called!
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    DLog(@"%@", _labelMessage.text);
    CGSize size = self.labelMessage.intrinsicContentSize;
    size.height = size.height + _btTryAgain.frame.size.height + 16;
    size.width = self.intrinsicContentSize.width;
//  size.width  += 16;
    return size;
}

#pragma mark - Methods

/** Refresh the UI when message content is changed. */
- (void)setSystemMessage:(SystemMessage *)systemMessage {
    _systemMessage = systemMessage;
    [self updateUI];
}

- (UIColor *)getBorderColor {
    if (_systemMessage.messageType == MessageTypeWarning) {
        return [UIColor yellowColor];
    } else if (_systemMessage.messageType == MessageTypePositive) {
        return [UIColor greenColor];
    } else {
        return [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}

- (void) hideButtonWithId:(MessageViewButtonId)buttonId {
    if (buttonId == MessageViewButtonIdClose) {
        _btClose.hidden = YES;
    } else if (buttonId == MessageViewButtonIdTryAgain) {
        _btTryAgain. hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, systemMessage: %@", [super description], _systemMessage];
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)didPressCloseButton:(id)sender {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(messageView:didPressButtonWithId:)]) {
        [_delegate messageView:self didPressButtonWithId:MessageViewButtonIdClose];
    }
}

- (IBAction)didPressTryAgainButton:(id)sender {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(messageView:didPressButtonWithId:)]) {
        [_delegate messageView:self didPressButtonWithId:MessageViewButtonIdTryAgain];
    }
}
```

Comment: In case if you are giving fix height to your view then please remove that & only give button bottom constraint from the view.

Comment: I am not giving fixed height to view in the xib. But it has height in the size inspector and during runtime that size is fixed.

Comment: You have used autolayout or autoresizing?

Comment: autolayout with constraints.

Comment: First of all, you are using the wrong approach for this. You are adding message view inside message view (check xib setup method).
Another thing I want to know how actually you are using this view in your application.

Comment: As in the screenshot, it will drop down from top. so it will be added as a subview on top of the current view, animated drop down.

Comment: Check this . it will Help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/36862795/4910767

Comment: i saw that, but thats not loading from xib. in my case the parent view keeps it size as it was in xib.