# UILabel cannot show its all letters

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

UILabel cannot show its all letters.
My app is like [now my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f4nX.jpg)

PhotoController (it is for this page)is

```
import Foundation
import MobileCoreServices
import UIKit
class PhotoController:UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    private var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = "Tap the PhotoSelect or Camera to upload a picture"
        //myImageUploadRequest()


    }
```

So,all letter of

```
label.text = "Tap the PhotoSelect or Camera to upload a picture"
```

is not shown in my app.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: label.numberOfLines = 0; By default UILabel will have only 1 line.

Comment: give number0fLines = 0

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Either make your label multi line or

```
   label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

Comment: if you are using `minimumScaleFactor` then no need of `numberOfLines`

Comment: @ Anbu :- I know that. Read my answer carefully, I have used word OR

Answer (score 1):

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Thats all you need :)

**EDIT:**

Setting line break modes to the label will help you get further improved O/P

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping //choose whichever matches ur requirement
```

Comment: @anbu-karthik : UILabels have intrinsic size. So unless he has applied height constraint to UILabel (I hope he has not) setting lineNumber to 0 will make the text grow more than one line and because of intrinsic size label will grow as well :)

Answer (score 0):

from storyboard

1. Constraints :

Give constant label height with relationship `>=`

2. Property

set number of lines = 0