# I want to apply Auto Layout to UILabel like flexible height & width

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I applied flexible height & width to my UILabel and now I want to use that type of functionality by using Auto Layout.

I am able to increase height and width of UILabel as Device width and height, but X and Y is not changed according to Device width and Height.

Ex:-

```
Device :- iPhone 7
UILabel :-
        X      : 20
        Y      : 120
        Width  : 300
        Height : 30


Device :- iPhone SE
UILabel :-
        X      : 20 
        Y      : 120
        Width  : 245
        Height : 25
```

Now problem is that Size of UILabel decrease with aspect ratio but X & Y coordinate was not changed.
According to flexible height & width that will set like 17 & 102, but in auto layout it was not change.

Constraint :

[Constraint Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52XnX.png)

Comment: use aspect ratio

Comment: UILables have intrinsic size that means they increase the height and width based on the content set. If you really want to increase the size of the label no matter what content it carries then simply apply leading, trailing,top and bottom constraint to parent view. So when parent view grows it will stretch the label as well. If the parentView is screen then u have what u wnt

Comment: add some more information.

Comment: Please refer to this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text

Comment: what about trait variation and size class?

Comment: Could you Please  show your constraints  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have fixed X and Y Position for your label (Which is not device specific)

If you need to achieve this you need to set X and Y according to Centre of your view

I have create to set centre X (For Y Pos )

[image]

[image]

And How I have set centre of Y Pos

[image]

**EXPLAINATION**

The centre of `UIView` according to self.view is `318.5` and required space from top is `20` so final multiplier is `20:318.5`

as every view has different centre 
For `Iphone SE`  centre would be around 17

Don't Forgot to set **First Item**  to `Label.Top` as we need 20 from TOP

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope it is clear to you :)

Comment: That's work :)
Thanks a lot for a great example... Jon Snow

Comment: @DevDev Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people
experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more
information, take a look at our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

I have attach a image to make a label height dynamically. Select trailing constraint and change relation from **"Equal" to "Greater Than Equal"**. Make sure number of line of label should should be **"0"**.

[image]