# UITableViewAutomaticDimension with auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

okay I am having trouble creating dynamic cells with tableview. My image collapse and looks like this. It works fine when the description is long but not when it is to short.

Image constraints are: width = 120, height = 160, top = 8, leading = 12.

Title constraints are: top = 8, leading to imageView = 8, trailing = 12.

Description constraints are: top to titleLabel = 5, leading to imageView = 8, trailing = 12, bottom = 12
[image]

Now instead of adding the bottom constraint to the description, I added it to the image and then the cell looks something like this.
[image]
Now the description is out of place and in the middle, where the it should be right under the title label.

Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: this link may be help you https://github.com/paresh1994/TableViewDynamicCellSize

Comment: I think this link is useful for you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446405/adjust-uilabel-height-depending-on-the-text?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Just curious would a horizontal stack view help here ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d Just tried it with a stack view and it did work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a little change to fix this

- Give Bottom of your `UIImageView` with >= relation with 12 constant
  value (750 Priority)
- Give Bottom of your Desc label with >= relation with 12 constant value (With That your label text will stick on top ))

So Now the Autolayout Engine has two things to follow

1. If your Label text is small then `UIImageView` will be consider as height
2. If your Label text is larger then it will be used as Cell height

Hope is is helpful

Comment: Prashant thanks. Did it your way with 0 but looked funny, used 12 instead and was much better.

Comment: @LuisRamirez I apologies   I didn't read your constant value Updated it Thanks :) Could you please mark it as accepted