# UILable Text incomplete

Tags: cocoa, xcode, uilabel

Hi i googled around a bit and didn´t find any solutions for my problem.
i fill a UILabels text with a large String, and sometimes (it doesn`t do so everytime) my UILabel.text is incomplete (not the whole NSString). It mostly happens with very large Strings but also with shorter ones.

Has anybody had that problem, or does know a workaround for this?
I really don`t know why this is happening...

Hint: I am using IB with a UILabel on a ScrollView. In the ViewDidLoad Method of the View i figure out the height of the UILabel with the sizeWithFont Method. 
I use WordWrap, AlignBaseline for my UILabel in IB

Answer (score 1):

i did change my method for the expected size to this:

```
UIFont *labelFont           = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
CGSize expectedLabelSize    = [testString sizeWithFont:labelFont 
                                  constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

this was wrong:

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize    = [testString sizeWithFont:IBOutletUILabel.font 
                                  constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

cobbal is right...

but i am confused, because it seemed to be ignoring the newline characters before, cause my label size was variating

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the [`numberOfLines`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines) to 0 in addition to setting word wrapping.

Comment: hi ive already  word wrapping and set numberOfLines to zero. both in Interface Builder, now i`ll try to set it programmatically. and see whats going to happen.

Comment: @user It might also be related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204000/iphone-uilabel-sizewithfont