# How to set UILable/UIButton(custom) Size after adding string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have to add number of labels/custom buttons in scroll view with there title.

so for that i get length of each string and multiply with it`s font size and get width of whole string but i am not get exact value for each label.

if any buddy have idea that tell me.

Thanks

Ankit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do Something like dis...!!!

```
NSString * titleString=pod.title;
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(200,999);
    CGSize size = [titleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    titleLabel=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 24, 200, size.height)] autorelease];
    [titleLabel setText:titleString];
    [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [titleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    titleLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [scrollView addSubview:titleLabel];
```

Comment: thanks for give ur time my friends... Hey suny i think this one also compatible  for UIButton(cus.).

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice method `sizeWithFont:`. You can look it up [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [sizeWithFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) method of [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html),

[iPhone UILabel sizeWithFont:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204000/iphone-uilabel-sizewithfont/3599071#3599071)

[How do I get -[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:] to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419222/how-do-i-get-nsstring-sizewithfontforwidthlinebreakmode-to-work)