# UILabel display problem

Tags: iphone

[image]

In the above figure it shows...

I need to display complete data in UILabel.

This is an alignment problem with UILabel

```
UILabel *lable=[[UILabel alloc]init];
lable.frame=CGRectMake(350, 25, 50, 50);
[lable setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[lable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lable setText:@"Leveraged Commentary & Data"];
```

I need to display completed setText on lable @"Leveraged Commentary & Data";

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: put  lable.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft; also set the lable.frame=CGRectMake(350, 25, increase this value, 50);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UILabel *lable=[[UILabel alloc]init];

lable.frame=CGRectMake(350, 25, increase this value , 50);
[lable setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[lable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lable setText:@"Leveraged Commentary & Data"];
```

You need to increase the width of the  label

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things for display complete text.

1) Increase the width of UILabel.

2) Increase the height and set no of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Can you increase the label width. Label is too small to display the text.Try this

```
lable.frame=CGRectMake(350, 25, 350, 50);
lable.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
```

Comment: You've increased the height, not width.

Answer (score 0):

Make your label's frame wider, it's only 50 points according to your code.
NSString has a method `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` which allows you to get the dimensions of the text.

Here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406212/sizing-a-uilabel-to-fit) with an accepted answer.