# i can't load all my text in view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, detailsview

In my application I have few views with longer text. 
In my detail view I have been imported text from database and for some short texts it works but for longer it make me problem. When I take smaller font it shows me all text so it loads it from database good but make some other problem.
My code for that part is:

```
case RestaurantItemTypeDescription : {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Restaurant Description"];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Restaurant Description"];
            }
            cell.imageView.image = nil;

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            CGRect rectLabel = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x+20, cell.frame.origin.y+10, cell.frame.size.width-20, cell.frame.size.height-20);
            UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectLabel];

            label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
            label.numberOfLines = 0;
            label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0]; //Same font used for calculating height
            label.text = item.itemText;
            label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            [cell addSubview:label];
//          [label release];
            //NSLog(@"description=%@", item.itemText);
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            break;
        }
```

I have autoresize atribute but it seams it doesn't work.

Can someone please tell me what to do? I was searching the web and it seams that there is no restriction about size of text in view. 
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to adjust the height of the label AND the height of the cell to account for the longer text.

There's a decent guide on how to do it [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/).

Answer (score 2):

Autoresize attribute is only used to resize when the size of the view is changed like when the orientation changes from portrait to landscape or when you invoke setFrame:

You need to resize the UILabel to make the label large enough to show all the text.  To do that you have to calculate how big the UILabel must be.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406212/154803) covers various options for doing that.

Comment: i implemented - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and CGSize withinsize = CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width-20, 1900); the last atribute gives me size and by changing it i change size of field. It is not perfect but do things for me... :)