# UILineBreakModeWordWrap is deprecated

Tags: uilabel, deprecated

Here's my code:

```
CGSize s = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]
               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, CGFLOAT_MAX) // - 40 For cell padding
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

I get a warning that UILinebBreakModeWordWrap is deprecated in iOS 6.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You need to use `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` in iOS 6

For your code try this:

```
NSString *string = @"bla";

CGSize s = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]
              constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, CGFLOAT_MAX) // - 40 For cell padding
                  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

an example on a label would be:

```
[label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Instead of

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Comment: Why Apple just changed name of it ? What's the purpose ?

Answer (score 14):

To maintain backward compatibility, you can create a macro as below:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
# define LINE_BREAK_WORD_WRAP NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
#else
# define LINE_BREAK_WORD_WRAP UILineBreakModeWordWrap
#endif
```

Comment: Why does Xcode still flag the warnings if the Macro is there?

Comment: Do you have min SDK <= ios 6? do you use swift or objective-C?

Comment: SDK is 9.2, Min target is ios7, Obj-C

Comment: Then use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping directly.