# UILineBreakModeWordWrap deprecated

Tags: ios, deprecated

I Have A Problem In My App when I wrote This Code UILineBreakModeWordWrap And I Got

> UILineBreakModeWordWrap deprecated : first deprecated in IOS 6 ""And
>   Some Time IOS 7""

My Code Is :

```
NSString *texto = [[superArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Text"];
CGSize tamanho=[texto sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240.0f, 480.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
UIImage *imagemBalao;
```

And

```
cell.label.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

And The Same Problem In This Code GKPeerPickerController

```
(void)peerPickerControllerDidCancel:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker{
    picker.delegate = nil;
}
```

And

```
(void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID toSession:(GKSession *) session {
    currentSession = session;
    session.delegate = self;
    [session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
    picker.delegate = nil;
    [picker dismiss];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you go and look at the definition of `UILineBreakMode` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping instead of UILineBreakMode. Here is the list of new enums

```
 enum {
        NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0,
        NSLineBreakByCharWrapping,
        NSLineBreakByClipping,
        NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead,
        NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail,
        NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle
      };
     typedef NSUInteger NSLineBreakMode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSString *texto = [[superArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Text"];

    CGSize s = [texto sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240.0f, 480.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

[another stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914788/uilinebreakmodewordwrap-is-deprecated)

Comment: Thank You Very Mach It's Helped Me In The First Error :)